# Custom URL rewrite for reviews in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, routing

I have a review page for each product which can be accessed through : "example.com/shop/feedback/review/index/product_id/2931/"

Where feedback is the module, review is the controller and index is the action.

Magento provides an automated URL rewrite for products and category based on urlkey where "example.com/shop/category-name/product-name" is rewritten to "example.com/shop/123/2931" for the router to make sense of the url.

I wanted to know if there is a way where I can rewrite "example.com/shop/feedback/review/index/product-name" to "example.com/shop/feedback/review/index/product_id/2931/" without using the manual url rewrite management tool since there would be hundreds of these pages and I can't really make one manually for each.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, no, there's no feature in Magento to automatically create URL rewrites for a product's review.  I don't know of any extension that does this, but searching through Magento Connect may prove useful.

You could implement a feature like this yourself — on every product save you'd add a custom rewrite object (store in `core_url_rewrite` for community edition) for your product, and then change the appropriate templates or URL generating code to know about these rewrites, but it would be a non-trivial project that's beyond the scope of a single Stack Exchange answer.

Comment: as far as I understand the question it is how to move from one custom url structure to another. Not about the url rewriting for reviews default reviews.

Answer (score 0):

As it your module, you can add a redirect in the controller to the new url structure.
So inside the action use 
`$this->_redirect('module/controller/action', array('product_id'=>123, var_name'=>'value'));`

If you want to add store code or subfolder *shop* in the url you may also use .htaccess for web-server level url rewrites.

Comment: Maybe a bit more information here would be useful.

Comment: @ David Manners, thanks for the note, will edit the answer when on PC (now from phone)

Comment: A redirect would essentially change the URL for the user, which is not what I am looking for. I think a rewrite would be the best way of doing this. Since here you are also assuming I have the product_id, which is not the case if I only have the urlkey of the product.